# how to fill slider partially in javafx 2

Tags: java, javafx-2

I want to fill track of slider with color as it progress forward (to the right). I can't use progress bar.
I tried to create a custom progress bar with navigation support but no luck. i tried to do it with css styling but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a layout pane (any kind you prefer) and add a progress bar and slider over it. make sure the slider's track is transparent and bind the slider's and progress's value.